# How to pass multiple function implementations in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

Reading about [higher order functions](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/04_functional/01_Higher-Order%20Functions) in Kotlin, I see a syntax for passing a function implementation ("inline") like the following one:

```
calculate(4, 5) { a, b -> a * b }
```

The `a, b -> a * b` part is actually a function passed to a function. Full snippet:

```
fun calculate(x: Int, y: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int {  // 1
    return operation(x, y)                                          // 2
}

fun sum(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y                                     // 3

fun main() {
    val sumResult = calculate(4, 5, ::sum)                          // 4
    val mulResult = calculate(4, 5) { a, b -> a * b }               // 5
    println("sumResult $sumResult, mulResult $mulResult")
}
```

Consider having a function that receives 2 functions, e.g.

```
fun calculate2(x: Int, y: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int, operation2: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int {
    //...
}
```

**How do I pass it 2 function implementations - "inline" (without first declaring the functions)?**

Trying to do [like the following](https://pl.kotl.in/Gf7DqKFKC?theme=darcula) gives me a compilation error:

```
calculate(4, 5) { a, b -> a * b} {a, b -> a + b }
```

Screencap:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
calculate(4, 5, { a, b -> a * b }, { a, b -> a + b })
```

or

```
calculate(4, 5, { a, b -> a * b }) { a, b -> a + b }
```